# How to make a ViewPager cycle between views?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want my ViewPager implementation to cycle between views instead of stopping at the last view. For example, if I have 3 views to display via a ViewPager, it should return back to the first View after the third View on fling instead of stopping at that third view. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

(Found nothing relevant on google)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766630/changing-viewpager-to-enable-infinite-page-scrolling