# ViewSwitcher to switch between views

Tags: android

Could anyone  please help me getting the dynamic paging with the three views? I have a situation where I'd like to use the pager, but have potentially hundreds of images to show, and need to keep in memory .

However  i wanted to be able to scroll through the multiple pages infinitely. In other words, when on the first page, be able to flip previous to the last page. Also when on the last page, be able to flip next to the first page. Then i have  a situation where i did not know how many pages i wanted to flip through. I should dynamically generate the number of pages and be able to flip through

Comment: What kind of views is it you want to scroll between?

Comment: thanks for the reply,my theme is to implement book with data from  a .txt file.my view must be a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think android has any in built view for this. But searching on net gave me two ways one is RealViewSwitcher, with little bit tweeking you could be using this

http://marcreichelt.blogspot.in/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html?showComment=1337585123909#c5836636640938589250

and the next is infinitepageviewer

[Changing ViewPager to enable infinite page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766630/changing-viewpager-to-enable-infinite-page-scrolling)

If you have made this can you please let me know I am in process of writing similar thing for my app.

I tried both of these, the only problem I faced is dynamic creation of views, having said that there should be some way out using these I am till trying them.