# Custom ViewGroup to make the view in viewgroup can slide cycle

Tags: android, android-viewpager

That means I want the view int the custom viewgroup can work like viewpager,but the different is the it **can slide from the last to the first(while swipe right)or form the first to last(swipe left).**
I had try below way.

1. set the class implements PageAdapter 's getCount() method as  follow:

   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424525/1872596 
   but then I get some bugs,where the device lock and unlocked minutes later, ANR occurs.
2. Custom the viewpager source code ,but failed.It is too hard for a freashman to read about 4000 lines source code.

I hope any one can help me,Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Extends from `ViewGroup` and override `dispatchDraw()`, and draw the first/last page if is over scrolling 
It is something like:

```
protected void computeCirculate(Canvas canvas) {
    if (isAllowCirculate()) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(-getWidth() * getPageCount(), 0);
        drawPage(canvas, getPageCount() - 1);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getWidth() * getPageCount(), 0);
        drawPage(canvas, 0);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Updated:

Please see my github project: [Android_PagedView](https://github.com/aizhang/Android_PagedView)

Comment: Any demo?or if Custom the android viewpager surcode ,how to custom?