# How to use swipe gesture in a view pager's page with android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, gesture

I need to take a view pager in an application which consist of three pages.

I am new to android view pager.

I have one view named `TestSwipingView` in second half of the screen and another view for the top half of the screen.

How do I configure only `TestSwipingView` as swipe-able?

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented it. It may give you some idea too.

Step 1 : In my main activity, I have made my page adapter and called it in onCreate().

```
public class SomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    private boolean mFromDropdown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_activity);

        Window window = getWindow();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        int width = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 1);
        int height = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * .85);
        window.setLayout(width, height);

        mFromDropdown = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromDropdown", false);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }
```

Step2: This is my Custom Adapter for your example:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                // Using different layouts in the view pager instead of images.

                int resId = -1;

                       //Getting my layout's in my adapter. Three layouts defined.
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    resId = R.layout.tutorial1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resId = R.layout.tutorial2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    resId = R.layout.tutorial3;
                    break;

                }

                View view = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);
                ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

        }

    }
```

Step 3 : My Layouts:

Main Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:text="Your Text"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout to put inside the ViewPager in MainLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="18dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:text="title1_secondscreen"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:text="header1_secondscreen"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/page2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tutorialText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#F3F3F4"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="footer1_secondscreen"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout to put inside the ViewPager in MainLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="18dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:text="title1_thirdscreen"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:text="header1_thirdscreen"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/page3" />

          <!--   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:text="@string/tutoril_text3"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="16sp" /> -->
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#F3F3F4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="footer1_thirdscreen"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you..:)..Good Luck..:)