# How to display different layouts with the ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, xamarin, setcontentview

In Xamarin, I currently have two different activities and I would like to combine these together and use a ViewPager.

One activity uses the following content view: `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MapWithOverlayLayout);`

The second activity uses the following content view: `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeScreen);`

Can I please have some help to code a simple ViewPager that can add the two above content views into a ViewPager and then show each of these content views via code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this one http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html. Also you can extends your adapter to PagerAdapter in which you can call your views.

Answer (score 1):

For a ViewPager, **you will need** `Fragments` instead of `Activities`.

Here is how to implement a `ViewPager` with **Fragments and different layouts**: [How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts/18413437#18413437)

The basic idea is that you create a `Fragment` for every layout you have, and then inside your `FragmentPagerAdapter`, load the correct `Fragment` depending on which page you are currently on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it in my other post and sorry about not posting the same code here.

Take a look at those links. It will help for sure.

[Android:How to create different view in ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090768/androidhow-to-create-different-view-in-viewpager/22117423#22117423)

Its a pretty simple implementation. You can define your own layouts and then use it in the view pager.

Here's my other post where you can get what you want to achieve:

[How to use swipe gesture in a view pager's page with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067586/how-to-use-swipe-gesture-in-a-view-pagers-page-with-android/22084254#22084254)

Hope this helps..:)