# Adding ViewPager inside activity's sub layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement the following UI. My base is an activity. But still need to display view pager feature inside my acivity. Do I need to change the base activity to some other component to achieve the same. Please guide me the best way to achieve the same. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: You just need to create a layout in xml that reflects what you are trying to do. Treat the ViewPager as you would any other type of view.

Comment: So basically you want to add a view pager in the same layout where your other components are

Comment: yes, I am trying to add view pager in same layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **take a look at my other post** :

[How to swipe xml layouts using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059545/how-to-swipe-xml-layouts-using-viewpager/22084847#22084847)

Lemme know if that's something you want. Good Luck .. :)

Comment: Mike , Your link resolved the issue.This implementation is having advanced features than what I was looking for. thanks a lot... :)

Comment: M glad I was able to help.. Good luck .. :)