# Curiosity Down/Up Swipe Animation & Fragments Populating Based On posts date

Tags: android, android-fragments

** in a nutshell: i want the scroll animation as shown in the gif, when the user swipes down/up it goes directly to the item, and its like a fling animation.

For the Date fragments, i guess its a `horizontal` `Recyclerview`.

What am looking as an answer is, a code example of the scroll animation, and a way to do the date thing, where i can auto populate the fragments based on the dates.

I've asked before about this and wmy question was not that clear. this app includes a swipe down/up style.

When u swipe down or up, the app doesnt let you swipe like a normal Scrollview, instead from the first touch (up for example) it navigates you to the next post.

Important note is the post/item in full size (item layout `match_parent` ?).

Also, every post has a date, and the app includes a calendar, when you swipe left or right, you navigates to dates and based on dates you get the posts.

What i want, hints or ways to do something like this. i'd love to provide a code but i've tried to draw the way up in my mind but couldn't think in of a logical way.

For fragments, i guess they're taking the `now` date, and the oldest date in the post, and based on that they're making (looping) fragments, each fragment has to load a posts based on the date (query to the API which gives date as param?).

Anyway, here's a GIF of the app which explains what im talking about. Im going to setup a bounty for this question, as im eager to achieve such a feature like this in my app.

https://gfycat.com/JadedMenacingAmericanalligator

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this by myself but I would like to help may be this will do the work
First use this library for the vertical scrolling one at a time 
https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager
or may be this one
https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

or may be use the pagersnaphelper of v7 support library like this

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

and for the horizontal scrolling you can use these libraries may be if you apply little bit of logic you will achieve it.

https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/looping-infinite-viewpager-with-page-indicator-in-android-ce741f25702a

https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

[Changing ViewPager to enable infinite page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766630/changing-viewpager-to-enable-infinite-page-scrolling)

let me know if it works.