# Android carousel/slider based on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider, carousel

How can I implement a carousel/slider based on Android ViewPager that looks like this template?
[image: template]

Comment: follow this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, @MaheshGiri, i did it, but how to do one page under other page, that one page overrides other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create carousel ViewPager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259627/how-to-create-carousel-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing like in image set some page margin

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(some width);
```

Comment: setPageMargin is not a method on ViewPager2

Comment: it is updated you can use ~myViewPager2.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(1500));~

Comment: Using this and ViewPager2 does not produce the requested effect.